# Get maximum value from database

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Number  Type  Name       Cost
12345   GM      A        891.80
12111   CH      A        2,341.67
11111   NN      A        4,704.59
11111   NN      B        1,534.17
11111   NN      C        1,653.60
```

I am trying to decide a name for a job. Each job has different number, type, name and cost. Some of the jobs have multiple names and costs for each name. The job name with the most cost will be the name for the job. How should I code this?

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; what have *you tried*, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: This is a confusing question. Are you working with a DBMS? What are these columns? A text file? Some Python data structure, a representation of your database tables?

Comment: Those datas are in excel file. I have been trying to use a for loop. What I have tried is: import openpyxl wb = openpyxl.load_workbook() sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1') for i in range(1, 100): if sheet1.cell(row=i, column=1).value == sheet1.cell(row = i+1, column = 1).value:. I got stuck here. I wanna find a max value for each name. but I don't know how to code for it. any help?

Comment: @D.Yang Why would you assume people are going to try to read and understand your code in a comment? *Edit* your original question and post your attempt *there*.

Answer (score 0):

As you have described the problem, you just need cost column to decide which job to choose. A simple implementation of your problem should be this:

```
name = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "C"]
cost = [891.80, 2341.67, 4704.59, 1534.17, 1653.60]

maxValue = max(cost)
maxValueIndex = cost.index(maxValue)
print("The best job is", name[maxValueIndex])
```

1) Get max value using "max" function and save it in **maxValue**.

2) Search inside "cost" list for value saved in "maxValue".

3) Print the best job.

Comment: I am not trying to find a job with most cost. I am trying to find a name for the job. Some of the jobs have multiple names and I need to decide the name for the job using the cost. I have alot more data than 5 lines so I am trying to use iteration or for loop. Too many data to use ur way. Thanks anyway for the response thou

Comment: Ok but do an example. How will be called a job after you analyze costs? And what is the criteria to choose the name? Be more clear please

Comment: Criteria for the job name is RM, CV, PM. Every job has at least one name with the cost. For example, job 1 has RM with 500 cost. job 2 has RM with 500 cost and CV with 1000 cost. Name for job 2 will be CV with 1000 cost. Is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

Put the table data into a database and do a 'select' then use these values to form the job name.

select number,type,name,Max(cost) from mytable group by type order by cost;

Output:

```
 Number      Type        Name        Max(cost)
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
12345       GM          A           891.8
12111       CH          A           2341.67
11111       NN          A           4704.59
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand what you said. I am new to python and coding. Can you please explain more in depth?